# how to use clause(where,and,not) sql

Tags: mysql

I have table absen like this:

[image: I have table absen]

and the table itungharian with coloumn like this:

> id_itung | id | total | itungtgl
>   (no data)

and query join like this:

```sql
 SELECT
      count(tgl) AS total,
      absen.id,
      pegawai.nama,
      pegawai.bagian,
      pegawai.bagian,
      pegawai.tglmasuk,
      gaji.jenis_gaji,
      gaji.jumlah, 
      itungharian.id AS id2,
      itungharian.itungtgl,
      CASE
           WHEN (weekday(tgl) <=3 )
           THEN date(tgl + INTERVAL(3 - weekday(tgl)) DAY)
           ELSE date(tgl + INTERVAL(3 + 7 - weekday(tgl)) DAY)
           END AS tglitung
FROM
      absen
JOIN
      pegawai ON pegawai.id = absen.id
JOIN
      gaji ON gaji.id = pegawai.id
LEFT JOIN
      itungharian ON itungharian.id = absen.id
WHERE
      absen.status = 'm'
GROUP BY
      absen.id,
      tglitung
```

and show this
[image: table join]

So I have problem how to join like this if values on cloumn id(table absen) same with itungharian.tgl and tglitung(result case when) same with itungharian.itungtgl don't show in join table

I have tried with sql like this:

```sql
 SELECT
      count(tgl) AS total,
      absen.id,
      pegawai.nama, 
      pegawai.bagian,
      pegawai.bagian,
      pegawai.tglmasuk,
      gaji.jenis_gaji, 
      gaji.jumlah,
      itungharian.id AS id2,
      itungharian.itungtgl,
      CASE
           WHEN (weekday(tgl) <= 3)
           THEN date(tgl + INTERVAL(3 - weekday(tgl)) DAY)
           ELSE date(tgl + INTERVAL(3 + 7 - weekday(tgl)) DAY)
           END AS tglitung
 FROM
      absen
 JOIN
      pegawai ON pegawai.id = absen.id
 JOIN
      gaji ON gaji.id = pegawai.id
 LEFT JOIN
      itungharian ON itungharian.id = absen.id
 WHERE
      absen.status = 'm' 
 AND
      NOT (CASE WHEN (weekday(tgl) <= 3)
           THEN DATE(tgl + INTERVAL(3 - weekday(tgl)) DAY)
           ELSE DATE(tgl + INTERVAL(3 + 7 - weekday(tgl)) DAY)END) = itungharian.itungtgl 
 AND
      NOT absen.id = itungharian.id
 GROUP BY
      absen.id,
      tglitung
```

but  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: It is not clear, if your provide the other tables schema and data, will help us to know, now i'm confused what u want?